# Gulp Plumber Breaking Sass Pipe

Tags: sass, gulp

I have no idea why my Sass task breaks when I'm using gulp-plumber. My Sass task looks like this:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src(['./src/scss/*.scss', './src/scss/**/*.scss'])
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass({
      includePaths : [
        './lib/basscss/scss',
        './lib/fluidbox/css'
      ],
      outputStyle: 'expanded'
    }))
    .pipe(prefix({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
      cascade: false
    }))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./_site/public/css'))
    .pipe(gzip())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./_site/public/css'))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}))
});
```

When I intentionally make an error in my Sass file(s), I get this error:

```
Error in plugin 'gulp-sass'
Message:
    src/scss/components/_cover.scss
  30:3  property "background-i" must be followed by a ':'
Details:
    column: 3
    line: 30
    file: /Volumes/Boba/Work/Sites/realph/src/scss/components/_cover.scss
    status: 1
    messageFormatted: src/scss/components/_cover.scss
  30:3  property "background-i" must be followed by a ':'
```

And that's it – it breaks the task. I have to abort the gulp task and re-run it from the top.

Any idea why this is happening? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the task you're running is not ended yet. You need to tell plumber to end the task when error is occured using `handleError` options. Here's my plumber configuration:

```
.pipe(plumber({
  errorHandler: function(err) {
    // display the error message
    console.log(err);
    // end the errored task
    this.emit('end') }
}))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This worked great! But I thought plumber handled errors by default?